# Website including pages/pages to my site

Tags: php, html, web

I have my site on index.html made in html+css., at my index.html i have this div id "content", where you put in main content to the page, and there's a link at the menubar that src to page2.php. When you press on the link it goes to the page2.php, but i want it to display inside the < div "content". 
In page2 i have Hello this is a test, in a echo..

I dont want to use frames.. should i split up my design on index.php, and then on page2.php include top & footer? or is there another way

```
function test() {
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(xhr.readystate==4 && xhr.status=200)
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
};

xhr.open("GET", "start.php", false);
xhr.send(null);
}

<a href="start.php" onclick="test(); return false;">Hjem </a> | 

<div id="content" ></div>
```

Comment: Install Firebug add-on for Firefox. Updated the answer, check it.

Comment: i guess ajax is too tough for you. So stick to what you know best. try it some other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you suggested in your question, you should look into splitting the index.html into a header and a footer. This will allow your site to work without javascript, and you may find that it is easier or makes more sense.

There's some quite good tutorials around, such as [this one](http://www.choicetemplates.com/tutorials.php?name=headfoot), but googling for [php header footer](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+header+footer) returns plenty of options.

Answer (score 1):

> Use AJAX to post a HTTP GET request to page2.php and display the result(echo) in the div container.

Somewhat like following, (will not work in IE)

```
<script>
function test(){
   var xhr = XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readystate==4 && xhr.status=200)
         document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
   };

   xhr.open("GET", "page2.php", false);
   xhr.send(null);
}

</script>
```

> [Try AJAX online](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

Comment: Can you show an example, the "echo" i said was just an example.. on page2.php i have an mysql query that displays some information from a table in the mysql database

Comment: I gave that a function, named "test".. now i did <a href="page2.php"  onclick="javascript: test();">click me</a> but it wont work, the page2.php just opens in a new page and not in content id

Comment: Yes ive did that now.. still nothing, just opens in a new..
please check updated question for how it looks

Comment: @Azzyh: you need to write the javascript code in `<script>` tags.
Updated the answer check it.

Comment: Install Firebug add-on for firefox.

Comment: @Azzyh: See what error you get on Firebug console (you need to enable it) or on Firefox's Error Console (ctrl+shift+j)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` and not only `"Hello this is a test"`, but you can also set any data from your MySQL database to `<div id="content">` innerHTML.